# Complicated table relationships

Tags: sql, database, relationship

There are 3 main entities: user, product and list of product. User can mark products as favorite. **Only** favorite products can be setted in product lists.

**Example 1:** I mark milk and bread as favorite. And add marked milk to list "for son".
Also, user can create empty product lists before adding favorite products to it.

**Example 2:** I create list "for sun", mark milk and bread as favotite and add marked milk to list "for sun".

Favorite products can exist without product lists. Product lists can exist without favorite products. Same product can be setted in different lists.

**Main problem:** product list must be linked with user. In case when it has favorite products, it can be linked through them. But in case when he does not have products it must be linked directly to user. 
[image: Schema of db]

Possible solution: create 4 tables: users, products, product lists and connecting table product lists - products. In product list for every user create list "favorite". But it breaks rules of normalization too, because i need duplicate adding products to list "favorite" whenever this products are added to another lists.
[image]

Comment: You could have a dummy "not-in-list" ProductLists row for every user and use your second diagram. Not sure if it's the best solution though. Perhaps better is a separate NonListFavorites table (UserID, ProductID)?

Comment: The 5 table diagram is weird because surely a product doesn't have to be a favourite to appear in a product list, and because there is no connection between product and product list.  The second diagram seems to suggest that a user may have multiple product lists; is that correct?  I think Brian's suggestion of 'your four table diagram plus a separate UsersFavouriteProducts table' is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a product will be in both the `ProductLists` named "favorite", and in some other `ProductLists`, then there will need to be two entries in `ProductListsProducts`.  This doesn't violate normalization.  You have two `ProductsLists` and two many-to-many relationships stored in `ProductsListsProducts`.  I don't see a problem with that modeling.

If every user will have a (potentially empty) list of "favorite" products that you would like to treat as a separate concept from your other `ProductsLists`, then just make your tables:

`Users`, `ProductsLists`, `ProductsListsProducts`, `Products`, and additionally a `UsersFavoriteProducts`.

`UsersFavoriteProducts` would contain a `user_id` and a `product_id`, and be handled separately from the typical `ProductsLists`.  `ProductsListsProducts` will not contain relationships for "favorite" products; the "favorites" relationship would only be stored in `UsersFavoriteProducts`.

Comment: I think it's wrong that product need to be added to UsersFavoriteProducts whenever it's added to a ProductsLists. Some sort of duplication.

Comment: You mean that any product in any of the user's `ProductLists` is implicitly a "favorite" product?

Comment: If all products in any of the `ProductLists` are implicitly also "favorites," just add them to the query for favorites.  You don't have to store them twice to get them in your select query.

Comment: Yes, only favorite products can be setted in product lists. Sorry, I will add it to description.

Comment: There might be a case when product will be in ProductsLists and will not in UsersFavoriteProducts. I need to control this rule in ORM layer. Is it bad?

Comment: @timrael: it looks like you've got conflicting requirements...  you'll need to figure out exactly what you want before you can model it.  If "favorites" is just any product that exists in any product list for that user, it doesn't require any special modelling and can just be handled with an 'exists' clause of your select queries.  The same is true if you have any kind of well-defined relationship between favorites and products.  Alternatively, if "favorites" is just a special kind of product list, it can be modeled as a product list or modeled separately.